# Android live video streaming with wowza streaming engine

Tags: android

am trying to stream video from android to wowza streaming engine running on local host and using the android library libstream, the problem is am not sending anything. The app works fine but on checking incoming streams from wowza there is nothing, I have set the ip address of my pc, port, application name and the stream name as STREAM_URL = "rtsp://192.168.1.227:1935/sound/myStream" correctly but with no success, i have also disabled the firewall on my pc. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the RTP protocol used by libstreaming uses by default UDP datagram packages to send the stream. Even if the packages are sent from Android, it is possible that the firewall on the server where Wowza is running is not opened up. Please check in Wowza admin console on the Server page the "RTP Datagram Starting Port" setting. The UDP port negotiated for a live source starts from that port number, than for each live source that port number is increased by 1.

Please check the the Wowza server firewall is opened up for a range of port starting with the value from the "RTP Datagram Starting Port" settings. You can open up untill 10000.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try that option